# How can I connect my skype with Jenkins for Java Testing

Tags: jenkins, automation, skype

I'm new in Jenkins from Java Automation Testing , I need to connect Jenkins with skype, How can I do this,I already search all stuff and I found Skype Plugin(with Instant Messaging Plugin) for Jenkins but didn't get how to use it